# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT and Multiple Lookup Tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I Have seven tables I am trying to join:

```
Table   programs
Column  id    program_name    program_description
        1     Self Help       Self Help Description...
        2     Wellness        Wellness Description...
        3     Education       Education Description...
______________________________________________________

Table   county
Column  id    county_name
        1     Stark
        2     Portage
        3     Wayne
_________________________

Table   services
Column  id    service_name    service_description
        1     Counseling      Counseling Description...
        2     Group Therapy   Group Therapy Description...
        3     Evaluation      Evaluation Description...
__________________________________________________________

Table   population
Column  id    population_name
        1     Adults
        2     Children
        3     Youth
_____________________________

Table   program_county
Column  id    program_id    county_id
        1     1             2
        2     1             3
        3     2             1
        4     2             2
_____________________________________

Table   program_service
Column  id    program_id    service_id
        1     1             2
        2     1             3
        3     2             1
        4     2             2
        5     2             3
______________________________________

Table   program_population
Column  id    program_id    population_id
        1     1             3
        2     2             1
        3     2             3
        4     3             1
_________________________________________
```

I am trying to write a query that would return one row for each program and retrieve the related rows in program_county,program_services, and program_population tables and lookup the names of those services, population and counties display them in one field each.  Like:

```
id   program_name    program_description         Counties           Services                                 Population Served
1    Self Help       Self Help Description...    Portage, Wayne     Group Therapy, Evaluation                Youth
2    Wellness        Wellness Description        Stark, Portage     Counseling, Group Therapy, Evaluation    Adults, Youth
```

I know I have to use joins and GROUP_CONCAT but I am admittedly very lost.

Comment: join your tables group by program id ,and put columns in group concat which you need as comma separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use outer joins if you want to see all programs regardless of whether they are associated to counties, services, or populations. Likewise you should use `coalesce()` around the values you are concatenating to handle NULL values properly.

Something like this should work:

```
select programs.id, programs.program_name, programs.program_description,
  group_concat(distinct coalesce(county.county_name,'')) as "Counties",
  group_concat(distinct coalesce(services.service_name,'')) as "Services",
  group_concat(distinct coalesce(population.population_name,'')) as "Population Served"
from programs 
  left outer join program_county on program_county.program_id = programs.id
  left outer join county on county.id = program_county.county_id
  left outer join program_service on program_service.program_id = programs.id
  left outer join services on services.id = program_service.service_id
  left outer join program_population on program_population.program_id = programs.id
  left outer join population on population.id = program_population.population_id
group by programs.id, programs.program_name, programs.program_description
order by programs.id
```

Comment: I like Ike!  So, to understand this better, I had to join program_county on programs to get the id's for each county matching the program ID, then join county with program_county to be able to get the county name matching the county ID's?  How does group by effect the results if you don't mind elaborating?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The `GROUP BY` clause must contain all columns that you want in the output that do not have an aggregate function applied to them. In this case you want 1 row for each program in the output, so you group by the columns you are selecting from the programs table.